# Duvida sobre a construção e relacionamentos entre as classes e o mapeamento no JPA

Tags: java, jsp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No diagrama de classe a seguir estou tentando fazer os seguintes relacionamentos entre classe onde uma demanda vai possuir um analista responsavel e um cliente solicitante. Gostaria de saber se o meu mapeamento ta certo se a lista fica na classe demandas ao contrario segue os models abaixo:

```
package br.com.deivsoft.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import br.com.deivsoft.enums.PrioridadeEnum;
import br.com.deivsoft.enums.StatusEnum;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DEMANDAS")
public class Demanda {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_DEMANDAS")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NRO_TICKET", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String nro_ticket;

    /* Enum de PRIORIDADE */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private PrioridadeEnum prioridade;

    /* Enum de STATUS */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "DEMANDA_ANALISTA", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ANALITAS"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DEMANDAS"))
    private List<Contato> contato;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "DEMANDA_ANALISTA", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ANALITAS"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DEMANDAS"))
    private List<Analista> analista;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dt_abertura;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNro_ticket() {
        return nro_ticket;
    }

    public void setNro_ticket(String nro_ticket) {
        this.nro_ticket = nro_ticket;
    }

    public StatusEnum getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public PrioridadeEnum getPrioridade() {
        return prioridade;
    }

    public void setPrioridade(PrioridadeEnum prioridade) {
        this.prioridade = prioridade;
    }

    public List<Contato> getContato() {
        return contato;
    }

    public void setContato(List<Contato> contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }

    public List<Analista> getAnalista() {
        return analista;
    }

    public void setAnalista(List<Analista> analista) {
        this.analista = analista;
    }

    public void setDt_abertura(Date dt_abertura) {
        this.dt_abertura = dt_abertura;
    }
}



package br.com.deivsoft.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import br.com.deivsoft.model.Equipe.grupamentoEnum;

@Entity
@Table(name ="ANALISTAS")

public class Analista {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_ANALISTAS")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "MATRICULA", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String matricula;

    @Column(name = "NOME", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "EQUIPE", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private grupamentoEnum equipe;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public grupamentoEnum getEquipe() {
        return equipe;
    }

    public void setEquipe(grupamentoEnum equipe) {
        this.equipe = equipe;
    }

    public List<Demanda> getDemanda() {
        return demanda;
    }

    public void setDemanda(List<Demanda> demanda) {
        this.demanda = demanda;
    }
}
```

Classe Cliente é a abaixo no codigo chamei de contato

```
package br.com.deivsoft.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTATOS")
public class Contato {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_CONTATOS")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "NOME", length = 155, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "MATRICULA", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String matricula;

    @Column(name = "LOTACAO", length = 155, nullable = false)
    private String lotacao;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="DEMANDA_CONTATO",
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID_CONTATOS"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_DEMANDAS"))
    private List<Demanda> demanda;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getLotacao() {
        return lotacao;
    }

    public void setLotacao(String lotacao) {
        this.lotacao = lotacao;
    }

    public List<Demanda> getDemanda() {
        return demanda;
    }

    public void setDemanda(List<Demanda> demanda) {
        this.demanda = demanda;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No diagrama de classe a seguir estou tentando fazer os seguintes relacionamentos entre classe **onde uma demanda vai possuir um analista responsavel e um cliente solicitante**. Gostaria de saber se o meu mapeamento ta certo se a lista fica na classe demandas ao contrario...

Com base no que você escreveu na sua pergunta, e mais especificamente na parte que destaquei, e no diagrama de classe que você postou(onde é possível ver os relacionamentos 1 -> 0..*, onde Cliente e Analista estão assinalados com 1 e Demanda está assinalada com 0.. *), eu diria que a demanda terá apenas um cliente e um analista, e estes últimos terão uma lista de Demandas, tanto cliente terá a
lista de Demandas que solicitou, e analista terá a lista de Demandas pelas quais foi responsável.

Assim sendo, o mapeamento seria assim:

Classe Demanda:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEMANDAS")
public class Demanda {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_DEMANDAS")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NRO_TICKET", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String nro_ticket;

    /* Enum de PRIORIDADE */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private PrioridadeEnum prioridade;

    /* Enum de STATUS */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CONTATOS")
    private Contato contato;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ANALISTAS")
    private Analista analista;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dt_abertura;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNro_ticket() {
        return nro_ticket;
    }

    public void setNro_ticket(String nro_ticket) {
        this.nro_ticket = nro_ticket;
    }

    public StatusEnum getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public PrioridadeEnum getPrioridade() {
        return prioridade;
    }

    public void setPrioridade(PrioridadeEnum prioridade) {
        this.prioridade = prioridade;
    }

    public List<Contato> getContato() {
        return contato;
    }

    public void setContato(List<Contato> contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }

    public List<Analista> getAnalista() {
        return analista;
    }

    public void setAnalista(List<Analista> analista) {
        this.analista = analista;
    }

    public void setDt_abertura(Date dt_abertura) {
        this.dt_abertura = dt_abertura;
    }
}
```

Classe analista:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="ANALISTAS")
public class Analista {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_ANALISTAS")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "MATRICULA", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String matricula;

    @Column(name = "NOME", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "EQUIPE", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private grupamentoEnum equipe;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "analista")// atributo analista da classe Demandas
   private List<Demanda> demandas;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public grupamentoEnum getEquipe() {
        return equipe;
    }

    public void setEquipe(grupamentoEnum equipe) {
        this.equipe = equipe;
    }

    public List<Demanda> getDemandas() {
        return demanda;
    }

    public void setDemandas(List<Demanda> demandas) {
        this.demandas = demandas;
    }
}
```

Classe Contato:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTATOS")
public class Contato {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_CONTATOS")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "NOME", length = 155, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "MATRICULA", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String matricula;

    @Column(name = "LOTACAO", length = 155, nullable = false)
    private String lotacao;

    @OneToMany
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contato")/atributo contato da Classe Demanda
    private List<Demanda> demandas;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getLotacao() {
        return lotacao;
    }

    public void setLotacao(String lotacao) {
        this.lotacao = lotacao;
    }

    public List<Demanda> getDemanda() {
        return demanda;
    }

    public void setDemanda(List<Demanda> demanda) {
        this.demanda = demanda;
    }
}
```

Esse é um tipo de assunto que só copiar e colar não resolve muito, é interessante tentar compreender os conceitos, e assim conseguir visualizar
a solução de modo amplo e poder reproduzir quando precisar, por isso recomendo que você procure algum material sobre o assunto, para começar
você pode verificar estes links:

[DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/hibernate-mapping-mapeando-relacionamentos-entre-entidades/29445)
[Documentação Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/pt-BR/html/collections.html)
[Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

E sem falar que você provavelmente uma hora ou outra, terá que definir
estratégias de [Cascade](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate) e [Fetch](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiQ9qDozJvZAhXOPpAKHapsCNsQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.baeldung.com%2Fhibernate-lazy-eager-loading&usg=AOvVaw1htJOwdU5Ne1_CjPvurZmO) para as coleções, assuntos que
não abordei porque foge do escopo da sua pergunta.

Comment: Resende vc poderia me mostrar como seria o diagrama relacional do banco de dados nesse caso?

Comment: Na verdade não tem muito segredo, demanda terá uma foreing key para cliente e outra para analista. Repare que não é um relacionamento N para N, e sim 1 para N, então não é necessário usar tabela união para nenhum dos dois relacionamento, apenas as foreing keys.